# Having Internet connectivity issues in windows server 2008 r2

Tags: server

I have recently installed windows server 2008 r2 on my virtual box. As soon as install active directory and create a domain. i loose internet connection on my machine.
I have assigned manual IP to my windows server 2008 r2 and have assigned the DNS same as its IP. 
Also when i install windows 7 on another virtual machine, at first i do get internet connection but as soon as i connect it to my domain, windows 7 virtual pc looses internet connectivity as well. I have configured bridge adapter on my network setting for virtual box.
Any ideas

Comment: windows 7 and windows server 2008 r2 both on virtual machine, i have a main win7 on which i am running virtual box. And on the virtual box i have installed win7 and windows server 2008 r2

Comment: This question looks like it belongs on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) as it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if correct forwarders are set in the DNS, try to resolve any public domain (i.e.; yahoo.com) via nslookup command (nslookup yahoo.com)and see if you are able to resolve. If you are not able to resolve the public domain names then you should set the forwarders correctly in DNS (May be you can use 8.8.8.8, 4.4.2.2 as forwarders, these are global google DNS resolvers)